# How to get uploaded file using koa2?

Tags: multipartform-data, koa2

I posted a `formData` to my koa project.  I got the following when I printed `ctx.request`

```
'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary5AThNwq75QDUwSIA','content-length': '517840'
```

However, why did I get `{}`' when I printed `ctx.request.body`?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use some middleware, for example [koa-body](https://github.com/dlau/koa-body) (but there is a lot of alternatives).

See [the example in official repository](https://github.com/koajs/examples/tree/master/upload)